# DXL simple attribute return

Tags: ibm-doors

i am new to DXL.

What i am trying to achieve:

I would like to create a DXL column in a module which displays the object's ForeignID plus a prefix.

What i tried:

*Module m = current*

*Object o*

*for o in m do {*

*string s = o."ForeignID"*

*displayRich("Prefix " s)*

*}*

but this only results in the entire list Prefix+ForeignID of all module's objects within each cell of the DXL column.

What do i need to change so every object will only show it's own Prefix+ForeignID within the DXL cell.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some information here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ermd/9.7.1?topic=definitions-dxl-attributes-layout-dxl-columns. Also check the DXL reference which is linked on that page

The code in DXL Layout columns is executed for each Object, there is a variable called "obj", which points to the Object which is being calculated at the moment (N.B. that is NOT the "current" Object, which is the Object that the user has clicked on).

Your code would simply be

```
string s = obj."ForeignID"
displayRich("Prefix " s)
```

or as a one-liner

```
displayRich("Prefix " obj."ForeignID" "")
```

(in this case, `display` would suffice. `displayRich` is only need when you have RTF (formatted) text, like the one in "Object Text".)